# Close accordion upon opening another accordion with different parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, accordion

I have the following accordion setup: https://jsfiddle.net/n4tmjaqd/1/

How can I adjust the function so that tab 1 closes when either tabs 2 or 3 open (and vice versa)? Tab 1 has a different parent than tabs 2 and 3, albeit with the same class. Would it even be possible to have such a function with different parents with the same class, or would I need to adjust the parent class name of say tab 1 and create a new function from there on? Guidance much appreciated.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.accordion .accordion-title').on('click', toggleAccordion);

  function toggleAccordion(event) {
    var target = $(event.target).closest('.accordion-item');

    target.parent('.accordion').find('.accordion-item').not(target).removeClass('is-open');
    target.toggleClass('is-open');
  }

});
```

```css
.accordion .accordion-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.accordion .accordion-title {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion .accordion-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 15px 15px;
}

.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .accordion-content {
  display: block;
}

.accordion .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 13px;
  right: 15px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border: solid #000;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .arrow {
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 1
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 2
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 3
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this at the beginning of the click event handler

```
$('.accordion-item').not($(event.target).parent()).removeClass('is-open');
```

Here is a working snippet ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mamounothman/gj8wp1yh/)):

```js
$(function() {

  $('.accordion .accordion-title').on('click', toggleAccordion);

  function toggleAccordion(event) {
   var text = $(event.target).find('span').text();
   if(text==="+") {
      $(event.target).find('span').text('-');
   } else {
      $(event.target).find('span').text('+');
   }
   $('.accordion-item').not($(event.target).parent()).removeClass('is-open');
    var target = $(event.target).closest('.accordion-item');

    target.parent('.accordion').find('.accordion-item').not(target).removeClass('is-open');
    target.toggleClass('is-open');
  }
  
});
```

```css
.accordion .accordion-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.accordion .accordion-title {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion .accordion-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 15px 15px;
}

.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .accordion-content {
  display: block;
}

.accordion .arrow {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    /* padding: 5px; */
    top: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    right: 15px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: inherit;
    /* border: solid #000; */
    /*border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;*/
    /* transform: rotate(45deg); */
    /* -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); */
}

/*.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .arrow {
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 1
      <span class="arrow">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
 <div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 2
      <span class="arrow">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 3
      <span class="arrow">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that works but now the accordion no longer closes when clicked on itself. Any way to get that working again?

Comment: Ok, let me check it.

Comment: @fiddle, check it now, I fixed it

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: I have a slightly different question: How can I adjust the code to set the icons to a set of plus (when accordion closed) and minus (when accordion open)?

Comment: let me check if I can add it

Comment: @fiddle, sorry my friend I have to leave now, will check it later if that's ok.

Comment: Another tiny issue: when the tab is open and if I click the icon to close that very tab, it doesn't close. It only closes when you click left of the icon. It's not a big deal but I'm curious to know why this happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello friend, were you able to have a look?

Comment: Hello, I just added +/- signs, but for the other issue, I'm not sure why the `<span>` is not propagating the event to the title element, sorry my friend, I will leave this to you :)